# How to cut off leading zeros from a TextEditingController (TextFormField)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a TextFormField with a controller. In this controller the initial value is 0, but the user can add decrease the number. This is the code:

```dart
TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  _setQuantity();
                  setState(() {
                    quantidade = int.tryParse(_controller.text);
                  });

                },
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(4),
                ],
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                ),
                cursorColor: AppColorSecondary,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: 
                  Colors.white,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

The Controller:

```
void _setQuantity() {
    Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false).setQuantity(
        int.tryParse(_controller.text));
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = TextEditingController(text: getSize().toString());
    _controller.addListener(_setQuantity);
    quantity = widget.size.quantity;

    super.initState();
  }
```

So, for example, the initial value of the TextFormField is 0, if I put 3 it keep the first zero:

```
// How it is now
// Initial State:
// 0
// I put a three:
// 03

//How I want:
// Initial State:
// 0
// I put a three:
// 3
```

How can I reach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onChanged:(value){
if (value[0] =="0") controller.text = value.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: With this code the zero is gutted but if I type the second value, it inputs at left... How to fix it?

Comment: Try `onChanged:(value){
if (value[0] =="0") value = value.substring(1);`

Comment: with this code it put the numbers at right but doesn't cut the first zero

Answer (score 0):

```
onChanged: (val){
          if(val.characters.characterAt(0) == Characters("0") && val.length > 1){
            // we need to remove the first char
            textEditingController.text = val.substring(1);
            // we need to move the cursor
            textEditingController.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: textEditingController.text.length);
          }
        },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).